# Sum of coefficients in a series

Tags: real-analysis

Assume we have a series written as

$$\sum_{n=-N}^{N}c(n)X(n,x)$$ can we find one coefficient $C$ such that

$$C\sum_{n=-N}^{N}X(n,x)=\sum_{n=-N}^{N}c(n)X(n,x)$$

by some function

$$C=f(c(n))$$

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: that's related to a weighted mean

Comment: Not sure I get the question. Can't you just take $C$ to be the quotient of the two sums? (assuming that $\sum\limits_{n=-N}^N X(n)$ is not zero)